# Low disk space for installation of apps

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

Hey guys I just installed ubuntu  a few days ago and used the first option of dual booting with windows7 after installing some apps and stuff I got and error saying that there is low disk space...I installed ubuntu on a 10gb partition and I still have 300gb to spare on my hard drive..please tell me how to increase this ubuntu partitions disk space>>THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot to the live USB/CD media, then install and run gparted.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted
```

This will allow you to resize partitions safely.